# Getting SHA512 hashed values out of SQL into C#

Tags: c#, sql, hash

I have a database that stores passwords. I use the following code to store the password of an user into a binary(64).

```
HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @ppassword)
```

I also use the following code to convert a password in a SHA512 hashString in  C#

```
    public static byte[] GetHash(string inputString)
{
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = SHA512.Create();  ;
    return algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));
}
public static string GetHashString(string inputString)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in GetHash(inputString))
        sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

However if I try to get the stored hash out of the databse I get a bytearray.
I tried many things like converting the bytearray to a hexstring but that doesn't seem tp work. How can I solve this, my goal is to compare the stored database hash with a string that is hashed in C#.

Comment: You need to simplify your question, your problem is not "how do I compare the stored database hash with a string that is hashed in C#", you know how to retreive your database hash as a `byte[]`, you know how to get you C# hash as a `byte[]`, now you just need to ask the question "How do I compare two `byte[]` to see if they are equal" This question has nothing do do with hashing or databases, it is a simple question of comparing two arrays and you will find a lot more answers for that question if you search for it.

Comment: Agree with @ScottChamberlain; there's no point in going to string...comparing byte arrays will be much more straightforward and faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the hashes to strings for the purpose of comparison isn't the most efficient way to do the work you're needing to do. Instead, you'll get way better performance comparing byte arrays. There are a number of ways to go about it...but even then, byte arrays are somewhat awkward to work with.

What I've done in the past, and recommend to you, is to make a struct that represents the kind of hash you're working with. I called the struct `Hash`. It has methods to *read to* and *write from* byte arrays. It has methods to compute the hash of a string, stream, or byte array. (Note that computing the hash of a byte array is different that reading a hash from a byte array.) Most importantly it has operators to compare hashes to each other...so you can do things like:

```
if ( hashA == hashB )
{
  //-->> do cool stuff...
}
```

The code in this example uses fixed-length arrays and pointer arithmetic, and therefore you have to set *allow unsafe code* in your project settings...but it makes hashes *normal* value-type things. You could do this without unsafe code but you'd lose the benefits of a value type. I did so much hashing that it was worth having the struct to help out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace UnsafeTypes
{
  /// <summary>Represents a hash of a string or byte array</summary>
  [StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
  public unsafe struct Hash: IComparable<Hash>
  {

    /// <summary>Returns the length of any <see cref="Hash"/></summary>
    public const int Length = 64;

    /// <summary>Returns a <see cref="HashAlgorithm"/> that the system uses to compute hashes</summary>
    public static HashAlgorithm GetHasher( )
    {
      return new SHA512Managed( );
    }

    /// <summary>Character map for byte array to string</summary>
    readonly static char[ ] hex = new char[ ] {
          '0', '1', '2', '3',
          '4', '5', '6', '7',
          '8', '9', 'a', 'b',
          'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

    /// <summary>Synchronization primitive</summary>
    readonly static object sync = new object( );

    /// <summary>Buffer for reading hashes from streams and arrays</summary>
    readonly static byte[ ] buffer = new byte[ Length ];

    /// <summary>ToString workspace</summary>
    static char[ ] hexChars = new char[ Length * 2 ];

    /// <summary>Returns a hash that has no value</summary>
    public readonly static Hash EmptyHash = new Hash( );


    /// <summary>A pointer to the underlying data</summary>
    fixed byte value[ Length ];


    /// <summary>Creates a hash from a string</summary>
    public Hash( string hashable )
    {
      fixed ( byte* bytes = value, sourceBytes = GetHasher( ).ComputeHash( Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes( hashable ) ) )
      {
        NativeMethods.CopyMemory( bytes, sourceBytes, Length );
      }
    }

    /// <summary>Creates a hash from a byte array</summary>
    public Hash( byte[ ] source, int index, int length )
    {
      fixed ( byte* bytes = value, sourceBytes = GetHasher( ).ComputeHash( source, index, length ) )
      {
        NativeMethods.CopyMemory( bytes, sourceBytes, Length );
      }
    }

    /// <summary>Copies the hash to the start of a byte array</summary>
    public void CopyTo( byte[ ] buffer )
    {
      CopyTo( buffer, 0 );
    }

    /// <summary>Copies the hash to a byte array</summary>
    public void CopyTo( byte[ ] buffer, int offset )
    {
      if ( buffer == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( buffer ) );
      if ( buffer.Length < ( offset + Length ) ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( nameof( buffer ) );
      fixed ( byte* bytes = value, dest = buffer )
      {
        NativeMethods.CopyMemory( dest + offset, bytes, Length );
      }
    }

    /// <summary>Returns a byte-array representation of the <see cref="Hash"/></summary>
    /// <remarks>The returned value is a copy</remarks>
    public byte[ ] GetBytes( )
    {
      var results = new byte[ Length ];
      fixed ( byte* bytes = value, target = results )
      {
        NativeMethods.CopyMemory( target, bytes, Length );
      }
      return results;
    }

    /// <summary>Compares this hash to another</summary>
    public int CompareTo( Hash other )
    {
      var comparedByte = 0;
      fixed ( byte* bytes = value )
      {
        for ( int i = 0; i < Length; i++ )
        {
          comparedByte = ( *( bytes + i ) ).CompareTo( other.value[ i ] );
          if ( comparedByte != 0 ) break;
        }
        return comparedByte;
      }
    }

    /// <summary>Returns true if <paramref name="obj"/> is a <see cref="Hash"/> and it's value exactly matches</summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The <see cref="Hash"/> to compare to this one</param>
    /// <returns>true if the values match</returns>
    public override bool Equals( object obj )
    {
      if ( obj == null || !( obj is Hash ) ) return false;
      var other = ( Hash ) obj;
      return CompareTo( other ) == 0;
    }

    /// <summary>Returns a .Net hash code for this <see cref="Hash"/></summary>
    public override int GetHashCode( )
    {
      unchecked
      {
        int hashCode = 17;
        fixed ( byte* bytes = value )
        {
          for ( int i = 0; i < Length; i++ )
          {
            hashCode = hashCode * 31 + *( bytes + i );
          }
          return hashCode;
        }
      }
    }

    /// <summary>Returns a hex string representation of the hash</summary>
    public override string ToString( )
    {
      lock ( sync )
      {
        fixed ( char* hexFixed = hex, hexCharsFixed = hexChars )
        {
          fixed ( byte* bytes = value )
          {
            for ( int i = 0; i < Length; i++ )
            {
              *( hexCharsFixed + ( i * 2 ) ) = *( hexFixed + ( *( bytes + i ) >> 4 ) );
              *( hexCharsFixed + ( 1 + ( i * 2 ) ) ) = *( hexFixed + ( *( bytes + i ) & 0xf ) );
            }
            return new string( hexChars );
          }
        }
      }
    }

    /// <summary>Reads a <see cref="Hash"/> from the provided stream</summary>
    public void Read( Stream stream )
    {
      lock ( sync )
      {
        var retryCount = 0;
        var bytesRead = ReadStream( stream, buffer, 0, Length, ref retryCount );
        if ( bytesRead == Length )
        {
          fixed ( byte* bytes = value, sourceBytes = buffer )
          {
            NativeMethods.CopyMemory( bytes, sourceBytes, Length );
          }
        }
      }
    }

    /// <summary>Tries hard to populate a <see cref="Hash"/> from a stream - across multiple reads if necessary - up to a point</summary>
    int ReadStream( Stream stream, byte[ ] buffer, int offset, int length, ref int retryCount )
    {
      const int maxStreamReadRetries = 3;

      var bytesRead = stream.Read( buffer, offset, length );
      var done = bytesRead == 0 || bytesRead == length;  // eos, timeout, or success
      if ( !done )
      {
        if ( retryCount++ >= maxStreamReadRetries ) return 0;
        bytesRead += ReadStream( stream, buffer, bytesRead, length - bytesRead, ref retryCount );
      }
      return bytesRead;
    }

    /// <summary>Writes the hash to a stream</summary>
    public void Write( Stream stream )
    {
      lock ( sync )
      {
        fixed ( byte* bytes = value, targetBytes = buffer )
        {
          NativeMethods.CopyMemory( targetBytes, bytes, Length );
        }
        stream.Write( buffer, 0, Length );
      }
    }

    /// <summary>Returns true if the hash has no value</summary>
    public bool IsEmpty( )
    {
      return Equals( EmptyHash );
    }


    /// <summary>Implements == operator</summary>
    public static bool operator ==( Hash a, Hash b )
    {
      return a.Equals( b );
    }

    /// <summary>Implements != operator</summary>
    public static bool operator !=( Hash a, Hash b )
    {
      return !a.Equals( b );
    }

    /// <summary>Converts a byte array to a <see cref="Hash"/></summary>
    public static Hash FromBytes( byte[ ] hashBytes, int offset = 0 )
    {
      if ( hashBytes == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( hashBytes ) );
      if ( ( hashBytes.Length + offset ) < Length ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( nameof( hashBytes ) );
      var hash = new Hash( );
      fixed ( byte* sourceBytes = hashBytes )
        NativeMethods.CopyMemory( hash.value, sourceBytes + offset, Length );
      return hash;
    }

  }

  class NativeMethods
  {
    [DllImport( "Kernel32", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "CopyMemory" )]
    internal unsafe static extern void CopyMemory( void* destination, void* source, uint length );
  }

  static class Extensions
  {
    /// <summary>Applies action to each element of the collection.</summary>
    public static void Do<T>( this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action )
    {
      if ( enumerable == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "enumerable" );
      if ( action == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "action" );
      foreach ( var item in enumerable ) action( item );
    }

  }
}
```